# Nested IF VBA using RIGHT function

Tags: vba, excel, function, nested-if

I need to make two macro buttons that increases and decreases, respectively, the value of a cell based upon it's decimal value.

For example: Cell AA8 currently = 117.292

IF the 3 digits after the decimal point (Right 3) = 317 then add 0.683 to the cell.

IF above is false then check if last digit (Right 1) = 0 or 5, if true then +0.02

IF above is false then add 0.03

The opposite will then need to be applied to the other macro.

For example: Cell AA8 currently = 117.292

IF the 3 digits after the decimal point (Right 3) = 000 then subtract 0.683 from the cell.

IF above is false then check if last digit (Right 1) = 0 or 5, if true then -0.03

IF above is false then subtract 0.02

Code I have tried

```
Sub TEST_UP()
If Right(aa8, 3) = "317" Then Range("aa8").Value = Range("aa8").Value + 0.683
Else
    If Right(aa8, 1) = "0 OR 5" Then Range("aa8").Value = Range("aa8").Value + 0.02
    Else
        Range("aa8").Value = Range("aa8").Value + 0.03
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to insert the "increment" button:

- Tab Development -> Insert Controls -> Button (Form Control)
- "draw" the button on the screen
- click "New" in the "Assign macro" dialog Box
- between the `Sub ...()` and `End Sub` statement type the following:

  ```
  With Range("AA8")
      Select Case True
          Case Format(Right(.Text, Len(.Text) - InStrRev(.Text, Application.DecimalSeparator)), "000") = "317"
              .Value = .Value + 0.683
          Case Right(.Text, 1) = 1, Right(.Text, 1) = 5
              .Value = .Value + 0.02
          Case Else
              .Value = .Value + 0.03
      End Select
  End With
  ```

Comment: When the value is .317 it works correctly. Any other value it adds 0.3 regardless of last digit :(

Comment: in my test it worked as per "specs": cell AA8 initial value =`.317` -> step 1) 1st condition matches :.317+ 0.683 = `1` step 2) 1st condition doesn't match,  2nd condition matches (last digit =`1`) -> 1+0.02= `1.02` step 3) 1st and 2nd conditions don't match -> 1.02+0.03= `1.05`  step 4) 1st condition doesn't match,  2nd condition matches (last digit =`5`) -> 1.05+0.02= `1.07` ... and so on

Comment: Sorry I was making a stupid mistake. Was supposed to be 0.003 and 0.002. Thanks so much